# How to configure BreezeJS Sharepoint adapter for cross-domain REST Calls

Tags: angularjs, rest, sharepoint, breeze, office365-apps

I am using BreezeJS sharepoint adapter for angular for developing an app on Office 365. I need to call the SP List REST api on the host web, from the app web. What is the way to accomplish this with Breeze? If this is not currently supported, is there a temporary work-around available?

Comment: My question relates to the Breeze SharePoint client side adapter only. BTW, Office 365 does not allow any server access. Also, Office 365 supports CORS already.

Comment: Not following then - are you getting an error with Breeze while making the cross-domain calls or are you not making calls to the server at all?  Do you have relevant code to show so it is easier to understand what is not working and a problem statement such as 'The server is throwing an error' or something?